# WEBM Videos not playing smoothly

Tags: video, vlc, totem, mpv-media-player

I have tried playing WEBM videos on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop but they don't play smoothly. With VLC and MPV, frames are being dropped but still the video freezes and doesn't match the audio. Totem plays the video well but pegs my cpu at 100 % utilization.
If I re-encode the video to matroska(mkv) the video plays smoothly with cpu utilization of roughly 10 %.
The WEBM video plays fine on Windows(dual-boot) on the same hardware ,and no frames are dropped.
Ubuntu-restricted-extras is installed.

**Video properties:**
dimension; 2048 × 1080
codec; VP9
frame rate; 23.98 frames per second
bit rate; N/A

**Audio;**
codec; Opus
channels; Stereo
sample rate; 48000 Hz
bit rate; N/A

here are some output from the terminal:
MPV output

```
regern@regern-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ mpv ./video1.webm
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (vp9 2048x1080 23.976fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (opus 2ch 48000Hz)
[vaapi] libva: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
[ffmpeg/video] vp9: No support for codec vp9 profile 0.
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 2048x1080 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:03 / 00:04:34 (1%) A-V:  0.488 Dropped: 3

Audio/Video desynchronisation detected! Possible reasons include too slow
hardware, temporary CPU spikes, broken drivers, and broken files. Audio
position will not match to the video (see A-V status field).

(Paused) AV: 00:00:13 / 00:04:34 (4%) A-V: 22.512 Dropped: 92
```

VLC output

```
regern@regern-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ vlc ./video1.webm
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[0000562eaa0f15b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_6
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f9788065b00] vaapi generic error: profile(19) is not supported
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[00007f9794c04e50] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
```

MY COMPUTER (neofetch)

```
regern@regern-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               regern@regern-Inspiron-15-3552 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Inspiron 15-3552 4.4.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 44 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2276 (dpkg), 12 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1366x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: farajas-light+orange 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: farajas-light+orange [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: farajas-icons-1.4 .1 [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Celeron N3060 (2) @ 2.480GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1821MiB / 3847MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: `mpv --vd-lavc-check-hw-profile=no /path/to/your/video` is this better?

Comment: @nobody .Runs a little better but Audio/Video desynchronisation persists

Comment: there is this error that shows both in vlc and mpv... could it be the issue?  [vaapi] libva: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed

Comment: yes i think so, get same message with `vainfo` But I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: `export  LIBVA_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so` start normal `mpv /path/to/your/video`   Any changes?

Comment: still desynchronized

Comment: `cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name` and look here https://github.com/intel/media-driver#supported-platforms  if your platform is supported.

Comment: mine is 400 BSW..Not supported

Comment: Having the same problem. The video is a screencast recorded with Ubuntu itself, using its PrintScreen (recording/screenshot) widget. — No idea how to solve.